# Automation Error. Exception Occurred when running a macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've recently been having issues running macros on one computer running Excel 2010 on Windows 7 Professional. Whenever I try to run a macro, I get an indefinite progress bar with a message 'Please wait...' and the workbook grays out slightly in the background. After a period of time, I get the error `Automation Error. Exception occurred` and the workbook closes.

For all intents and purposes, the specific macro doesn't seem to matter, as I've written basic `MsgBox Hello World` scripts and they throw the same error.

What's unique is that I do not get this error if I either (1) run the macro from within the VBE, or (2) have the VBE open in the background. It seems that having the VBE open allows me to run macros.

I've done some searching and haven't found any solutions that matched my situation. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: This was asked a day or two ago... let me see if I can find it. Edit: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728143/why-do-i-need-to-have-the-vba-editor-window-open-for-my-macro-to-work).

Comment: @findwindow Thanks for the link. While it sounds like some of the symptoms may be the same, I'm not sure that it's the same problem. I'm not calling any userforms, and the error occurs even on the simplest lines of code. Again, thanks for the help. I'll continue researching as well to see if I can't figure it all out.

Comment: Do you have any personal macros that could be firing?

Comment: @findwindow I don't have any personal macros